# I have trouble updating Android studio

Tags: android, ubuntu

Whenever I try to update a patch file (13MB) by clicking on "Update and Restart" to upgrade to a more stable version of Android studio, the download dialog box closes after the download and automatically closes the application. When I start it again, and check for updates, I am prompted to make the same update again.
I use Ubuntu 16 by the way.
Is there a way I could make the update successfully other than download the entire android studio that is (430MB) again?

Answer (score 2):

It means patch file can't update your existing Android Studio.
You have to manually download Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Other).

Now extract all contents and save them somewhere.
Then, run this command in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo tar xvzf android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip
cd android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux./studio.sh
```

Note: If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

> $ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
>   lib32z1

Source >>> [linux-32-bit-libraries](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries)